# ubuntu 20.04 wifi activation failed cannot connect to wifi

Tags: 20.04, wireless

-- met the wifi connection issue, it was ok few days ago, but now my internal wifi card cannot connect to school's wifi, but if I connect it to a router (no internet connected to the router) it can connect to the router's net no issue, here are the networkmanagement output

```
Feb 22 11:03:48 Zephyrus NetworkManager[962]: <info>  [1645545828.3496] device (p2p-dev-wlo1): supplicant management interface state: disconnected -> authenticating
Feb 22 11:03:48 Zephyrus NetworkManager[962]: <info>  [1645545828.3544] device (wlo1): supplicant interface state: authenticating -> associating
Feb 22 11:03:48 Zephyrus NetworkManager[962]: <info>  [1645545828.3544] device (p2p-dev-wlo1): supplicant management interface state: authenticating -> associating
Feb 22 11:03:48 Zephyrus NetworkManager[962]: <info>  [1645545828.3948] device (wlo1): supplicant interface state: associating -> associated
Feb 22 11:03:48 Zephyrus NetworkManager[962]: <info>  [1645545828.3948] device (p2p-dev-wlo1): supplicant management interface state: associating -> associated
Feb 22 11:03:48 Zephyrus NetworkManager[962]: <info>  [1645545828.5821] device (wlo1): supplicant interface state: associated -> completed
Feb 22 11:03:48 Zephyrus NetworkManager[962]: <info>  [1645545828.5822] device (wlo1): Activation: (wifi) Stage 2 of 5 (Device Configure) successful. Connected to wireless network "Stevens-Net"
Feb 22 11:03:48 Zephyrus NetworkManager[962]: <info>  [1645545828.5822] device (p2p-dev-wlo1): supplicant management interface state: associated -> completed
Feb 22 11:03:48 Zephyrus NetworkManager[962]: <info>  [1645545828.5822] device (wlo1): state change: config -> ip-config (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Feb 22 11:03:48 Zephyrus NetworkManager[962]: <info>  [1645545828.5824] dhcp4 (wlo1): activation: beginning transaction (timeout in 45 seconds)
```

any thoughts on this issue ?
thank in advance.

Comment: had test on different net work, tried to add 'band=bd' to force the wifi card connect 2.4Gwifi, not working, but it can connect 5G wifi from a router, but cannot connect to my phone's hotspot, no idea why.

Comment: ok, now I am basically confirmed, this is caused by mt7921 wifi card, it has issue with kernel 5.13.0-30, both wifi and Bluetooth will not work, if upgrade to latest kernel 5.16, then both will work, but problem is wifi is not smooth, stuck here and there, and nvidia driver also has some issues, cannot be loaded, so I just boot using old kernel, at least I can use nvidia card, for wifi and bluetooth I have to use 2 usb adapters to do these basic jobs, maybe later when 5.16 kernel is stable, and I have free time, I will try it again, make the hardware fully used.

Comment: there are two ways, first upgrade the kernel to 5.16, it will have a better support mt7921 wifi card, but need to install nvidia drivers and linux-headers, some other problems may appear, such as the touch pad not working, keyboard backlit turned off, etc, these issues need one by one solved afterwards, second method is I just replace the mediatek mt7921 wifi card with an intel ax210 wifi 6 card, I will post my results later when I finish the test.

Comment: Please remove the 3 comments and add this information to the body of the question via edit. Comments are where someone trying to help you asks you questions, it is not the place you add more info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok, the issue finally solved by replace the asus laptop's mediatek mt7921 wifi card with intel ax210 wifi 6 card, because the kernel 5.13.30 already have intel's wifi driver, u don't need do anything else, then the connections are back. hope this can help someone try to fix the asus laptop wifi issue when using ubuntu os.